# Make Firefox ignore web video and display flash

Tags: html, video, html5-video

```
<video controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <embed src="Untitled-2.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="480" height="270" />
</video>
```

I thought Firefox would fallback to the Flash if it couldn't play the HTML5 video, but it just displays the HTML5 controls and a blank screen. Is there a way to force it to ignore the mp4 video source?

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with Firefox and MP4, it just seems to break when it sees it. It's supposed to ignore it and fallback like you say, but doesn't.

e.g. if I have an OGG video (which FF will play) if it's after the MP4, it doesn't work. Put it before, and it's fine (obviously because it never gets to the MP4).

I know this doesn't help solve your issue though, I don't know any way of getting FF to ignore the MP4 other than browser sniffing and serving it different code (and who wants to do that?)